# Where can i find a good article on cross-class communication for AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm looking for a good tutorial that outlines how you communicate in between external classes and how to properly scope the classes and ect but am struggling to find a article. Does anyone have any advice on tutorials i can take to better familiarize myself with these concepts?

Comment: What are external classes? If you mean classes, which are loaded at runtime, you'll want to implement an interface in order to interact with the loaded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for tutorials on general object-oriented programming. 
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/

As an overview though - To communicate with different classes in most object-oriented languages you can either:

Inherit from that class. (using the 'extends' keyword with AS3)

```
class Square {
    var x, y, width, height;
}

class Rectangle extends Square{
    function changeDimensions( newWidth, newHeight ):void {
        super.width = newWidth;
        super.height = newHeight;
    }
}
```

Have an instance of that class as a property of your class (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a).

```
class Tire {
    var radius, tred;
}

class Car {
    var width, depth;
    var make;
    var leftBackTire:Tire;
    var rightBackTire:Tire;
    var leftFrontTire:Tire;
    var rightFrontTire:Tire;
}
```

Pass an instance of the outside class to a function your class's as a function parameter.

```
class Person {
    var position;
}

class Treadmill {
    function movePerson( personToMove:Person ):void {
        personToMove.x += 5;
    }
}
```

Create a global instance of the outside class (outside the scope of **any** class) and access it anywhere.

```
class World {
    var inhabitance;
}

var earth:World = new World();

class InhabitanceCalculator {
    function calcuateEarthInhabitance():void {
        earth.inhabitance = 3000000000;
    }
}
```

(AS3 particularly) Use a pre-defined event system where your class registers a function to be called for a certain event, that an external class transmits to anyone listening.

```
class Scoreboard extends EventDispatcher {
     var points = 0;
     Scoreboard(player:Player) {
         player.addEventListener("PlayerKilledEnemy", onPlayerKilledEnemy);
     }
     function onPlayerKilledEnemy():void {
         points += 1;
     }
}

class Player extends EventDispatcher {
    function killEnemy():void {
        //Aaaah!
        dispatchEvent( new Event("PlayerKilledEnemy") );
    }
}
```

Please note that I haven't added the 'public' keyword to the variables/classes/functions. You'll need to prepend that for anything that you want outside classes to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I would also spend some time looking at custom events. When used properly, they can provide an extremely versatile pipeline between classes in AS3.